# Facebook Ads API - how to add multiple rules to custom audience api call in PHP

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to add 2 rules to api call like below:

```
$parameters     =       "name=TEST-Registered-CA&";
$parameters     .=      "subtype=WEBSITE&";
$parameters     .=      "retention_days=180&";
$parameters     .=      'rule={"and":[{"url":{"i_contains":"thankyou.asp"}},{"url":{"i_contains":"HotelVenueState=CA"}}]}';

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/act_12345/customaudiences?access_token=123456&$parameters;
```

> When i try to run above on Facebook Graph Explorer, it gives following error 
>   "(#2654) Invalid JSON for rule: Supplied string for rule is not valid JSON" Rerence url ([enter link description here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/custom-audience-website/v2.2)

Can any one tell me what i am doing wrong with json ?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you always properly URL-encode query parameters. Manually building the URL by concatenating strings will often result in URLs that won't be parsed correctly.

Here's how you could build the URL above:

```
<?php

$parameters = array(
  'access_token' => '123456',
  'name' => 'TEST-Registered-CA',
  'subtype' => 'WEBSITE',
  'retention_days' => '180',
  'rule' => '{"and":[{"url":{"i_contains":"thankyou.asp"}},{"url":{"i_contains":"HotelVenueState=CA"}}]}'
);

$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/act_12345/customaudiences?'.http_build_query($parameters, null, '&');
```

Comment: Thanks David for your help but it was another issue and it was even a bug and i had asked from facebook Developers directly and they told me the exact solution for this which i am going to answer myself shortly.

Comment: Thanks for the update Naveed. I'd be interested to see what the solution was myself.

Comment: David, i posted solution and you can try that and it will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

In recent update in facebook v2.3 they have added one more parameter with those calls which is (method=post) and when i added this and it worked for me. so code should be like this

```
$parameters     =       "method=post&";
$parameters     =       "name=TEST-Registered-CA&";
$parameters     .=      "subtype=WEBSITE&";
$parameters     .=      "retention_days=180&";
$parameters     .=      'rule={"and":[{"url":{"i_contains":"thankyou.asp"}},{"url":{"i_contains":"HotelVenueState=CA"}}]}';

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/act_12345/customaudiences?access_token=123456&$parameters;
```